# Stuck overlaying a play button ontop of a thumbnail image

Tags: html, css

**I'm trying to overlay a play button onto a thumbnail image.**

On clicking the image a lightbox appears showing the video (using Colorbox Drupal module).

I've tried wrapping the image in a div called "newvideo" which has the background image of my play button. However I can't seem to get it to show!

**The code**

```
<style>
video {
  max-width: 580px;

.newvideo { position: relative; }

.newvideo a {
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   background: url(http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/play-button-crm-homepage2.png);
   height: 55px;
   width: 57px;
   top: 60px;
   left: 130px;
}

.newvideo a:hover {
       background: url(http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/play-button-crm-homepage-11.png);
}

</style>
```

**HTML**

```
   <div style="display: none;">
<div id="id-of-content">
<video controls poster="/sites/default/files/image/crm-systems-poster_0.png">
  <source src="/sites/default/files/image/CRM-Systems-Video.ogv" type="video/ogg">
  <source src="/sites/default/files/image/CRM-Systems-Video.mp4" type="video/mp4">

  <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/crm-system-image.png" title="CRM System image">

</video>
</div>
</div>

     <div class="newvideo">
         <a class="colorbox-inline" href="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/CRM-Systems-Video.mp4?width=580&height=330&inline=true#id-of-content">
        <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/CRM-Systems-Video.png" title="CRM System image"> </a>
        </div>
```

Any advice?

**Fidde**: http://jsfiddle.net/8ojo5m88/3/

Comment: Please use a code snippet or jsfiddle

Comment: Thanks @OddDev have just added fiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you place an image within an element, it sits over the background of that element so, unless that image has transparency, you're not going to be able to see the background.

One way to achieve what you want, without the need for any additional markup, is to use an absolutely positioned pseudo element on the `<a>` tag.

[More information on pseudo elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements)

**EXAMPLE** (Updated to include `:hover` state)

```css
a{
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
}
a:after{
    background:url(http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/play-button-crm-homepage2.png) center center no-repeat;
    bottom:0;
    content:"";
    display:block;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
}
a:hover:after{
  background-image:url(http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/play-button-crm-homepage-11.png);
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/CRM-Systems-Video.png"></a>
```

Comment: This is great but doesn't it mean I'm unable to add a hover to the play button since the playbutton is already a pseudo class?

Comment: Added a width and height to the video and it sorted it out! Thanks! Will put in a fiddle for readers.

Comment: That's a different issue related do something else you've done.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nileshmahaja/p5Ldd3cc/

I have altered your HTML markup and modified CSS code.
please have a close look

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="newvideo">
     <a class="colorbox-inline" href=""></a>
     <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/CRM-Systems-Video.png" title="CRM System image" /> 
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
newvideo { 
    position: relative;
    width:320px
}

.newvideo a {
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   background: url(http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/play-button-crm-homepage2.png);
   height: 55px;
   width: 57px;
   top: 0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin:auto;
}

.newvideo a:hover {
       background: url(http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/play-button-crm-homepage-11.png);
}
```

Comment: Works fantastic on JSFiddle but not on my Drupal site. Any idea why: https://www.workbooks.com/test-video (See second image).

Comment: Be aware that, while technically valid HTML, some screen readers will ignore empty anchors, making them inaccessible.

Comment: I can't See  ".newvideo a " Class is getting aplied in your site, can you please cross check the Class name and spelling?

Comment: Just checked the code and in Chrome Developer tools and I can see it in the <div>?